# How do I test to see that a directory is empty in ANT?

Tags: ant, directory

How can one test to see that a directory is empty in ant?

Comment: I can't believe nobody has asked this...well ANT is kind of old I guess...

Comment: ...oh well, it works for what I'm automating.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`pathconvert`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task to do that, with the `setonempty` property.

```
<pathconvert refid="myfileset"
             property="fileset.notempty"
             setonempty="false"/>
```

will set the property `fileset.notempty` only if the fileset those refid is `myfileset` is not empty.

You just have to define `myfileset` with your directory, and no excludes do get a directory empty test:

```
<fileset dir="foo/bar" id="myfileset"/>
```

See [this example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200512.mbox/%3C4397C619.5010106@gmx.de%3E) for a use case:

> use the setonempty attribute of pathconvert, with the value "false".
>   This way, if the fileset is empty, the property will not be set. this
>   is good since targets check with their if attribut whether a property
>   is set or not.
>
> so you do something like :
>
> ```
> <fileset dir="foo/bar" id="myfileset"/>
> <target name="fileset.check">
>     <pathconvert refid="myfileset" property="fileset.notempty"
> setonempty="false"/>
> </target>
> <target name="main" depends="fileset.check" if="fileset.nonempty">
>     <!-- your main work goes here -->
> </target>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a complement for [tonio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048134/938111).

In this example `cvs checkout` is emulated using `git` commands:

- `git clone` when `dir` is empty
- `git fetch` else

---

```
<target name="cvs_checkout" depends="git.clone, git.fetch" />

<target name="git.clone" depends="check.dir" unless="dir.contains-files">
  <echo message="Directory ${dir} is empty -} git clone" />
  <exec executable="git">
    <arg value="clone"/>
    <arg value="${repo}"/>
    <arg value="${dir}"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="git.fetch" depends="check.dir" if="dir.contains-files">
  <echo message="Directory ${dir} contains files -} git fetch" />
  <exec executable="git" dir="${dir}">
    <arg value="fetch"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="check.dir">
  <fileset dir="${dir}" id="fileset"/>
  <pathconvert refid="fileset" property="dir.contains-files" setonempty="false"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

scripted solution that sets a property only when the directory is empty:

```
<script language="javascript">
    tests = new java.io.File(project.getProperty("source.test.java.dir"));
    if (tests.list().length == 0) {
        java.lang.System.out.println('no tests: skip.test=true');
        project.setProperty("skip.test", true);
    }
</script>
```