# execute Ant task if TWO conditions are met

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, is-empty, ant-contrib

The above [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) script implements `if dir_is_empty then git-clone else git-fetch` using Ant-1.7.1 core statements:

```
<target name="update" depends="git.clone, git.fetch" />

<target name="check.dir">
  <fileset dir="${dir}" id="fileset"/>
  <pathconvert refid="fileset" property="dir.contains-files" setonempty="false"/>
</target>

<target name="git.clone" depends="check.dir" unless="dir.contains-files">
  <exec executable="git">
    <arg value="clone"/>
    <arg value="${repo}"/>
    <arg value="${dir}"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="git.fetch" depends="check.dir" if="dir.contains-files" >
  <exec executable="git" dir="${dir}">
    <arg value="fetch"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

(see [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086175/938111))

---

**But how to implement a `target` enabled by two conditions?**

`if dir_does_not_exist or dir_is_empty then git-clone else git-fetch`

my current attempt:

```
<target name="git.clone" 
        depends="chk.exist, chk.empty" 
        unless="!dir.exist || dir.noempty" >
  [...]
</target>

<target name="chk.exist">
  <condition property="dir.exist">
    <available file="${dir}/.git" type="dir"/>
  </condition>
</target>

[...]
```

---

I would prefer Ant-1.7.1 core statements. But I am open about other possibilities as [Ant contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509079/938111), or [embedded script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509912/938111)... Feel free to post your ideas...

(See also question [Execute ANT task just if a condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14562904/938111))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even when bound to Ant 1.7.1 you may combine your 3 chk targets into one, see the [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) part in the snippet.
Since Ant 1.9.1 (better use Ant 1.9.3 because of bugs in Ant 1.9.1 [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107844)) it is possible to add [if and unless attributes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) on all tasks and nested elements, so no extra target needed, f.e. :

```
<project xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

  <condition property="cloned" else="false">
    <and>
      <available file="${dir}/.git" type="dir" />
      <resourcecount when="gt" count="0">
        <fileset dir="${dir}/.git" />
      </resourcecount>
    </and>
  </condition>

  <exec executable="git" unless:true="${cloned}">
    <arg value="clone" />
    <arg value="${repo}" />
    <arg value="${dir}" />
  </exec>

  <exec executable="git" dir="${dir}" if:true="${cloned}">
    <arg value="fetch" />
  </exec>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) documentation on [targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html#targets):

> Only one propertyname can be specified in the `if`/`unless` clause. 
>   If you want to check multiple conditions, you can use a dependend target for computing the result for the check:
>
> ```
> <target name="myTarget" depends="myTarget.check" if="myTarget.run">
>      <echo>Files foo.txt and bar.txt are present.</echo>
> </target>
>
> <target name="myTarget.check">
>      <condition property="myTarget.run">
>          <and>
>              <available file="foo.txt"/>
>              <available file="bar.txt"/>
>          </and>
>      </condition>
> </target>
> ```

Moreover, there were some discussions on dev@ant.apache.org and user@ant.apache.org mailing-lists:

- [Using multiple properties in the 'if' and 'unless' conditions](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/using-multiple-properties-in-the-if-and-unless-conditions-td1363405.html) (June 2006)
- [Support mutliple if and unless](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/Support-mutliple-if-and-unless-td1352536.html)  (August 2008)
- [Multiple conditions satisfying in an ant target](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-conditions-satisfying-in-an-ant-target-td1353116.html)  (October 2008)

---

For example, the following `target` combines two properties (`dir.exist` and `dir.noempty`) to create another one (`cloned`) using operators `<and>` and `<istrue>` (many other [operators are documented](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) as `<or>`, `<xor>`, `<not>`, `<isfalse>`, `<equals>`, `<length>`).

```
<target name="chk" depends="chk.exist, chk.empty" >
  <condition property="cloned">
    <and>
      <istrue value="dir.exist"   />
      <istrue value="dir.noempty" />
    </and>
  </condition>
</target>
```

The above `property` `"cloned"` is used by targets `git.clone` and `git.fetch` as follows:

```
<target name="update" depends="git.clone, git.fetch" />

<target name="git.clone" depends="chk" unless="cloned" >
  <exec  executable="git" >
    <arg value="clone"   />
    <arg value="${repo}" />
    <arg value="${dir}"  />
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="git.fetch" depends="chk" if="cloned" >
  <exec executable="git" dir="${dir}">
    <arg value="fetch"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="chk.exist" >
  <condition property="dir.exist" >
    <available file="${dir}" type="dir" />
  </condition>
</target>

<target name="chk.empty" >
  <fileset dir="${dir}" id="fileset" />
  <pathconvert refid="fileset" property="dir.noempty" setonempty="false" />
</target>
```