# Ant if:true. Setting property to true won't cause the task to executed

Tags: ant, macros

In Ant 1.9.1, you have the ability to use [if and unless attributes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) on most tasks.

I have a macro I've defined where I'm trying to run these tasks:

```
<property name="test.templates"     value="true"/>
....
<target name="test.templates"
    description="Test the autoconfiguration templates and answers">
    <test.templates
        if:true="test.templates"
        template.root.dir="${main.dir}"
        answers.dir="${main.config.dir}"/>
</target>
```

However, this won't run my Macro -- even though the property `test.templates` is set to true. If I remove that line, my test.template macro will work.

Is there a problem using `if:true` in a user defined Macro? What's the best way to get around this issue?

Comment: I noticed you have a target, property and macro all called "test.templates"

Comment: Filled a bug report after problem still remains with new ant release from December 29, 2013 - see my updated answer EDIT (2) for details.

Comment: Solution found - see my updated answer EDIT (3) !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) :

> Since Ant 1.9.1 it is possible to add if and unless attributes on all
>   tasks and nested elements using special namespaces.

Didn't use the new if and unless attributes in a macrodef until now, but the following snippet works :

```
<project xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

    <property name="foo" value="true"/>

    <macrodef name="foobar">
     <attribute name="bla"/>
     <attribute name="whentrue"/>
     <sequential>
       <echo if:true="${@{whentrue}}">@{bla}</echo>
     </sequential>
    </macrodef>

     <echo>${ant.version}</echo>
     <foobar whentrue="foo" bla="yada,yada"/>

    </project>
```

Notice => the property syntax `<echo if:true="${@{whentrue}}">`, it doesn't work when using @{whentrue} only.

Output :

```
 [echo] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013
 [echo] yada,yada
```

My other try :

```
<macrodef name="foobar" if:true="foo">
 <attribute name="bla"/>
 <sequential>
   <echo>@{bla}</echo>
 </sequential>
</macrodef>

 <echo>${ant.version}</echo>
 <foobar bla="yada,yada"/>
```

didn't work :

```
... Problem: failed to create task or type foobar
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Also assumed that something like `<foobar bla="yada,yada" if:true="foo"/>` would work :

```
<project xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

  <property name="foo" value="true"/>

  <macrodef name="foobar">
   <attribute name="bla"/>
   <sequential>
     <echo>@{bla}</echo>
   </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <echo>${ant.version}</echo>
  <foobar bla="yada,yada" if:true="foo"/>

</project>
```

output, no error but macrodef doesn't get executed :

```
[echo] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Seems like there are still some inconsistencies in that area, as this feature is spanking new.
Maybe we should file a bug !?
-- EDIT (1) --
Just found a [comment from 2007 by Peter Reilly](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28882#c12) (he has implemented the if / unless feature) in the ant bug database providing a snippet with a macrodef.

-- EDIT (2) --
Although the new Ant release 1.9.3 from December 29, 2013 ([see releasenotes here](http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/apache//ant/README.html)) fixed a bug related to the new if: and unless: attributes (https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55885) our problem still remains. Thus i opened a bug report, see ant bug database [bugid 55971](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55971).

-- EDIT (3) --
Finally the solution is found. Beside the bugfix for [Bugid 55885](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55885) the Ant Release 1.9.3 provides also a bugfix for the documentation of the new if: and unless: attributes => [Bugid 55359](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55359) showing that `if:true="${propertyname}"` instead of `if:true="propertyname"` has to be used.
So your macro should work after upgrade on Ant 1.9.3 like that :

```
<property name="test.templates"     value="true"/>
....
<target name="test.templates"
 description="Test the autoconfiguration templates and answers">
  <test.templates
   if:true="${test.templates}"
   template.root.dir="${main.dir}"
   answers.dir="${main.config.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the work you put in! We were using antcontrib's `<if/>`, but I thought this would be a more elegant way of handling the issue, but was surprised when it didn't work.

Comment: @Rebse: It'd be nice if you edited this answer to put the solution at the top instead of the bottom (under several not-solutions).  If not for your "I solved it!" comment on the question, I would have given up on your answer before getting to the end.