# How to fail an ant build if a property is not empty

Tags: ant

I have an ANT build file which has the line-

```
<java classname="arq.sparql" fork="true" outputproperty="javaresult" errorproperty="javaerror">
```

Now I want add the condition to fail the build of the property 'javaerror' is not empty.
So I have the condition written like this :

```
<fail message="${javaerror}">
 <condition>
  <not>
   <equals javaerror=""/>
  </not>
</condition>
</fail>
```

But this did not work, can you please help.

Kind regards
Som

Comment: Edited the headline, changed 'variable' to 'property' as (core) ant has no variables.

Answer (score 6):

Your equals condition has the wrong syntax, it will work like that :

```
  <fail message="${javaerror}">
   <condition>
    <not>
     <equals arg1="${javaerror}" arg2=""/>
    </not>
  </condition>
  </fail>
```

see [Ant manual conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) for details
**-- EDIT --**
Alternatively you could use the [new if/unless feature introduced with Ant 1.9.1](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) but you should use Ant 1.9.3 because of bugs in Ant 1.9.1 [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107844)

```
<project xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

 <property name="javaerror" value="whatever"/>

 <fail message="${javaerror}" unless:blank="${javaerror}"/>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for

```
<fail message="failed" if="javaerror"/>
```

[Fail ant task doc](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html)

Comment: This will also fail if javaerror="" means it will fail as soon as ${javaerror} is set but it should only fail if ${javaerror} != ""