# how to change variable depending on OS in ant

Tags: ant

I am using more then one target for setting the variable name depending on OS.

```
<target name="checkos">
  <condition property="isWindows">
    <os family="windows" />
  </condition>
  <condition property="isUnix">
    <os family="unix" />
  </condition>
</target> 

<target name="if_windows" depends="checkos" if="isWindows">
  <property name="path" location="deploy.exe"/>
</target>

<target name="if_unix" depends="checkos" if="isUnix">
  <property name="path" location="deploy.sh"/>  
</target>
```

How can i set it in the single target.
I used if and condition but it doesn't allow it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

With ant >= 1.9.1 use the [new if/unless feature introduced with Ant 1.9.1](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) but you should use Ant 1.9.3 because of bugs in Ant 1.9.1 [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107844)

```
<project 
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>

<target name="setos">
 <condition property="isWindows">
  <os family="windows" />
 </condition>
 <property name="path" location="deploy.exe" if:true="${isWindows}"/>
 <property name="path" location="deploy.sh" unless:true="${isWindows}"/>
</target>

</project>
```

otherwise with ant < 1.9.1 use something like :

```
<target name="checkos">
 <condition property="isWindows">
  <os family="windows" />
 </condition>
</target> 

<target name="if_windows" depends="checkos" if="isWindows">
 <property name="path" location="deploy.exe"/>
</target>

<target name="if_unix" depends="checkos" unless="isWindows">
 <property name="path" location="deploy.sh"/>  
</target>
```

Comment: I am using ant 1.9.4. but it is giving me error with if condition.
Error is 'The prefix "if" for attribute "if:true" associated with an element type " property" is not bound.

Comment: Oh i got the solution. 
We need to use this to use if unless.
        <project name="tryit"
        xmlns:if="ant:if"
        xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
        >

Comment: Sorry - forgot about that in my snippet - only linked to the ant manual. New edit now contains the namespace declarations.