# Ant: conditional execution in macrodef

Tags: actionscript-3, ant

I've created a macro to compile `.swf` from `.as` sources (Flash projects) :

```
<macrodef name="compile">
  <sequential>
    <mxmlc file="@{input}" output="@{output}"/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Once created, I call it in my `build.xml` :

```
<target name="compile.app1">
  <compile input="App1.as" output="app1.swf"/>
</target>
```

To avoid compiling my `App1` each time, I've added the task `<uptodate>` in `<compile>` :

```
<macrodef name="compile">
  <sequential>
    <uptodate property="swf.uptodate" targetfile="@{output}">
      <srcfiles dir="@{src}" includes="**/*.as"/>
    </uptodate>
    <mxmlc file="@{input}" output="@{output}"/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

But at this point, I don't know how I can bind the `swf.uptodate` property with the `mxmlc` task. Here is what I would like to do :

```
IF NOT swf.uptodate
  EXECUTE mxmlc
ELSE
  do nothing.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for antcontrib, with ant >= 1.9.1 use [the new if/unless feature introduced with Ant 1.9.1](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) (better use Ant 1.9.3 because of bugs in Ant 1.9.1 [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107844))
To activate that feature you need the namespace declarations, as seen in the following snippet :

```
<project 
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>
<macrodef name="compile">
  <sequential>
    <uptodate property="swf.uptodate" targetfile="@{output}">
      <srcfiles dir="@{src}" includes="**/*.as"/>
    </uptodate>
    <mxmlc file="@{input}" output="@{output}" unless:true="${swf.uptodate}"/>/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
</project>
```

Otherwise when using ant <= 1.9.1 you may use [script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) with builtin javascript engine, if you want to avoid using ant addons like antcontrib.