# How to conditionally set arg value of exec task?

Tags: if-statement, ant

I've got an ant build script which I should modify. Specifically I should make a subversion checkout conditional: currently only the trunk gets checked out, the new version should checkout a given branch if needed.

```
<target name="do-svn-checkout" depends="init"
    <property name="branch" value=""/>
  <exec executable="svn">
    <arg value="checkout"/>
    <arg value="-r"/>
    <arg value="HEAD"/>
    <arg value="http://t01/java/trunk"/>
    <arg value="zzz"/>
    <arg value="--password"/>
    <arg value="xxx"/>
    <arg value="--username"/>
    <arg value="yyy"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

The property `branch` will be set via the command line like for instance `-Dbranch=mybranch`.

If the property `branch` is empty, the trunk should be checked out, but if the property has any other value, the respective branch should be checked out, like `http://t01/svn/hlfg/HLFG/java/branch/the-value-of-the-property`. So depending on the property the respective arg-value of the `svn` call should be modified.

Is it possible to solve this with basic Ant or would I need to use an inline script?

Answer (score 15):

When using Ant >= 1.9.3 it's a piece of cake with [the new if/unless feature introduced with Ant 1.9.1](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html)
(but you should at least use Ant 1.9.3 because of bugs in Ant 1.9.1, [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107844))

Don't forget the namespaces to activate that feature, f.e. :

```
<project
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>

 <property name="foobar" value=" "/>

 <echo if:blank="${foobar}">foobar blank !</echo>
 <echo unless:blank="${foobar}">foobar not blank !</echo>

</project>
```

in your case something like :

```
<target name="do-svn-checkout" depends="init"
 <property name="branch" value=""/>
 <exec executable="svn">
   <arg value="checkout"/>
   <arg value="-r"/>
   <arg value="HEAD"/>
   <arg value="http://t01/java/trunk" if:blank="${branch}">
   <arg value=".." unless:blank="${branch}">
   <arg value="zzz"/>
   <arg value="--password"/>
   <arg value="xxx"/>
   <arg value="--username"/>
   <arg value="yyy"/>
 </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Ant 1.9.x [If and Unless](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) was new to me. Cool.

Comment: Just checked: I've got 1.8.4 running. I will take this as an occasion to ask the sysadmin for an upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a wrapper target which depends on two other targets - one of which does trunk checkout, the other of which does branch checkout - and each of which is [conditional](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless) on existence of your optional branch property.

You could further abstract the exec call into a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) to which you pass the trunk or branch url.

For example:

```
<project name="test" default="do-svn-checkout">

    <target name="do-svn-checkout" depends="do-svn-trunk-checkout, do-svn-branch-checkout"/>

    <target name="do-svn-trunk-checkout" unless="branch">
        <svn-checkout svn-url="http://t01/svn/java/trunk"/>
    </target>

    <target name="do-svn-branch-checkout" if="branch">
        <svn-checkout svn-url="http://t01/svn/hlfg/HLFG/java/branch/${branch}"/>
    </target>

    <macrodef name="svn-checkout">
        <attribute name="svn-url"/>
        <sequential>
            <echo message="svn-url=@{svn-url}"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```

Output with no branch property defined:

```
do-svn-trunk-checkout:
     [echo] svn-url=http://t01/svn/java/trunk

do-svn-branch-checkout:

do-svn-checkout:
```

Output with branch property defined:

```
do-svn-trunk-checkout:

do-svn-branch-checkout:
     [echo] svn-url=http://t01/svn/hlfg/HLFG/java/branch/mybranch

do-svn-checkout:
```