# How to use macrodef?

Tags: ant, antlr

Lets assume this is my code.  buildJar is my macrodef.

```
    <target name="build"> 
     <buildJar build.dir="module1"/>
     <buildJar build.dir="module2"/>
     </target>
```

How to invoke macrodef "buildJar" based on some condition? For example, above code can be:

```
    <target name="build">
        <if module="module1" >
            <buildJar build.dir="module1"/>
        </if>
        <if module="module2" >
           <buildJar build.dir="module2"/>
        </if>
    </target>
```

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25864709/127035) give you two good options.

Answer (score 0):

Ant supports [if and unless attributes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html). These can be combined with a directory check using the [available task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html):

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:if="ant:if">

  <macrodef name="greeting">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <sequential>
      <echo message="found @{name}"/>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <available property="found.module1" file="module1"/>
  <available property="found.module2" file="module2"/>

  <target name="build">
    <greeting name="module1" if:true="${found.module1}"/>
    <greeting name="module2" if:true="${found.module2}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```