# How to invoke same target by passing different parameter values using antcall?

Tags: ant, antlr

How to invoke same target by passing different values to the parameter?
I wanted to invoke target using antcall.
Based on some falg i wanted to invoke a target by passing different values to the parameter using param.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use antcall, better use [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) (introduced with Ant 1.6) instead !!
I won't go into details, just search the web for 'antcall vs. macrodef' and similar..
See also [Writing Better Ant Scripts: Techniques, Patterns and Antipatterns](http://pjug.org/docs/ant.pdf)

Some snippet :

```
<project xmlns:if="ant:if">

 <macrodef name="foobar">
  <attribute name="foo"/>
  <attribute name="verbose"/>
  <sequential>
   <echo>@{foo}</echo>
   <echoproperties prefix="ant" if:true="@{verbose}"/>
  </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <!-- use foobar macrodef with different parameters (attribute values) -->
 <foobar verbose="yes" foo="1. yada,yada"/>
 <foobar verbose="no" foo="2. blabla.."/>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] 1. yada,yada
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Thu Sep 18 09:31:05 CEST 2014
[echoproperties] ant.core.lib=C\:\\ant194\\lib\\ant.jar
[echoproperties] ant.file=C\:\\area51\\ant\\tryme.xml
[echoproperties] ant.home=C\:\\ant194
[echoproperties] ant.java.version=1.7
[echoproperties] ant.library.dir=C\:\\ant194\\lib
[echoproperties] ant.version=Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
[echo] 2. blabla..
```

Comment: In my first test (ant 1.7), the properties were always printed. It seems that we need to upgrade ant at least to 1.9.3 for `if:true` to behave correctly. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102601/ant-iftrue-setting-property-to-true-wont-cause-the-task-to-executed]

Comment: @Seki yes you need to use ant 1.9.3 for `if:true` feature. Nevertheless the snippet is only for demonstration of reuse with different parameters(attribute values), which is independent from that new ant feature.

Comment: In this example how to invoke <buildJar> based on some condition?                                                                                                                                                                                                  <target name="buildAllJars"> <buildJar build.dir="tools"/> <buildJar build.dir="module-A"/> <buildJar build.dir="module-B"/> </target>    <macrodef name="buildJar"> <attribute name="build.dir"/> <jar destfile="lib/${build.dir}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}/classfiles"/> </macrodef>

Comment: @user3492304 with Ant >= 1.9.3 use new if/unless feature <buildJar build.dir="..." if:true="..."> with Ant <= 1.9.3 use the old way.Create a checking target with a condition, afterwards use a second target holding your macrodef calls like that <target name="..." depends="yourchecktarget" if="PropertySetByCondition">